# Handling Subscript and superscript in xml

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I want to handle the supertext and subtext for XML element:

```
<Property>
 <content> X<sup>^{2}<\sup> is used </content>
</Property>
```

to be shown like that :

```
X² is used
```

While using :

```
<xsl:value-of select="Property/content/text()"/>
```

Thank you

Comment: There are existing XML formats like MathML which then have stylesheets to transform to HTML with CSS. If you make up your own non XML format (like `X^{2}`) then you have to implement a lot yourself, with XSLT 2.0 using regular expressions like `xsl:analyze-string` might help but I would first consider whether you can't use existing formats.

Comment: What do you mean by "*shown*"? Shown where? In a browser? And what exactly are the rules here? One example is far from being sufficient to establish a method "*to handle the supertext and subtext*".

Comment: Use MathJax (http://www.mathjax.org). It's already done for you.